# How to set shorter caching time for a paragraph

Tags: caching, paragraphs

I have made a paragraph that shows social media wall (based on PHP Social Stream-module). The problem is that the wall isn't updated except when the global cache is recycled.

I have tried (in vain so far) to find out what is the correct way to make the caching "more agile" for that paragraph.

The paragraph is only using the paragraph twig and a a small MYTHEME_preprocess_paragraph__PARAGRAPH_NAME-function.

As it is placed on the front page on a site under quite a heavy load, I would prefer it not to be un-caching the whole page (not even talking about whole site).

Any suggestions?

wbr

hank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reload that paragraph block via AJAX.